# Replace Broadcom "wl" driver with "b43"

Tags: 10.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, and in my laptop there is a Broadcom BCM4312 WLAN card.
`lspci` output:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g (rev 01)  
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 04b5  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18  
    Memory at f4500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3  
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information <?>  
    Capabilities: [e8] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable-  
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00  
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting <?>  
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel <?>  
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 81-ac-1d-ff-ff-12-54-92  
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>  
    Kernel driver in use: wl  
    Kernel modules: wl, ssb
```

So as you can see, the current (and default) driver is `wl` - installed with Jockey.
But I have another Ubuntu based distribution on my laptop (BackTrack linux), which is also 10.04, but it has the `b43` driver installed and the overall performance is much better. So I would like to install it on this OS too, but even google didn't help me.

So my question is how to install the latest `b43` driver on my Ubuntu?

Comment: How is it in ubuntu 12.04? the aim is to activate the possibility of an Accesspoint - b43 would support this... http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Comparison_of_recent_drivers
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Ubuntu.2FDebian - the hardware must be able to do this because under windows i can use the trial version of connectify.me and my android phone recognize the wpa-wifi-accesspoint but not the wep-accesspoints made by ubuntus networkmanager... that's realy interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Under the desktop menu System > Administration > Hardware/Additional Drivers, the b43 drivers can be activated for use.

Restart.

Edited:

Install dkms.deb, patch.deb, fakeroot, and bcmwli. Those packages are in Ubuntu installation CD in the following paths:

```
/pool/main/d/dkms.deb
/pool/main/p/patch.deb
/pool/main/f/fakeroot
/pool/restricted/b/bcmwli
```

Enable STA driver in additional driver.

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: b43-fwcutter is already installed, but still it isn't in use. And jockey-gtk only shows the current STA driver.  "These package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driverfor use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4321-, andBCM4322-based hardware."

Comment: Is it not listed in Additional Drivers?
What does `sudo modprobe b43` give?

Comment: Nothing. Absolutely nothing :/

Comment: Try with my last edited version of the answer.

Comment: Ok, now it worked! Thanks for Your help!!! I installed those packages from the CD, but I deactivated the STA driver (You sad to activate), and I wrote `sudo modprobe b43` instead of wl, and now it works. Thanks again!